# If I upgrade my netbook from Windows 7 Starter to Windows 7 can I have a dual monitor setup?

Tags: windows-7, upgrade, netbook, multiple-monitors

I think Microsoft wants me to pay for a dual monitor setup for my Acer Netbook (I get it for free with Unbuntu Netbook remix).

I'd be willing to upgrade but I wouldn't put it past them to make me believe paying to have Windows 7 upgraded will let me use my netbook's screen along with another monitor when in fact it won't.

Has anyone upgraded their netbook to Windows 7? Can you have a dual monitor setup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upgrading to at least Home Basic should give you multiple monitor support. According to [this post](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7install/thread/422801d5-89de-494d-8cc1-6f4fc21c2ac0) on the Microsoft forums, starter is the only version without support for it.

I would **first make sure** you can use both monitors with netbook remix. Some netbooks with a VGA output have hardware limitations that will disable the built in screen when an external monitor is plugged in.

Comment: Is Home Basic even available unless you're in an "emerging market"?

Comment: in my post I mention that I'm aware of dual monitor support in Ubuntu Remix. I'm dual booting W7S and UBNR 10.04

Comment: @Randolph probably not.

Comment: @DJT I wasn't sure if you tested it by that statement. In that case you do not have the hardware limitation.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 Start Edition is limited to one monitor - you are correct. See here:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itprogeneral/thread/39c6bdee-ee7a-442b-842b-c46fefdbd111

If you upgrade that restriction will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

It is disabled on Windows 7 Starter edition (see [this chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_7_editions#Comparison_chart) on Wikipedia).

As for the netbook running a bigger version of Windows, your mileage may vary, but it will be slower. Home Premium will get you multiple monitor support, but you may have to disable certain features.